# How to select data in SQL based on a filter which changes if there is no data in a specific table column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables similar to the three below. I need to join the first two tables based on id, and then join the third table based on second name. However the last table needs a filter where the city should be equal to London unless age is empty in which case the city should equal Manchester.

I tried the code below using CASE statement but it is not working. I am new to SQL so I was not sure how can I combine a where statement with an if clause where the filter for the selection changes depending on whether there is data in a different column than the one used to filter by. The DBMS I am using Toad for Oracle.

FIRST.NAME.TABLE

```
ID  FIRST_NAME  ENTRY_DATE
1   JOHN            09/09/2019
2   NICOLA          09/09/2019
3   PATRICK         05/09/2019
4   JOAN            01/09/2019
5   JAKE            09/09/2019
6   AMELIA          01/09/2019
7   CAMERON         09/09/2019
```

SECOND.NAME.TABLE

```
ID  SECOND_NAME     ENTRY_DATE
1   BROWN           09/09/2019
2   SMITH           09/09/2019
3   COLE            05/09/2019
4   HOUSTON         01/09/2019
5   FARRIS          09/09/2019
6   HATHAWAY    01/09/2019
7   JONES           09/09/2019
```

CITY.AGE.TABLE

```
CITY    SECOND_NAME   AGE
LONDON        BROWN 24.00
LONDON        SMITH 
MANCHESTER     COLE 30.00
MANCHESTER  HOUSTON 66.00
LONDON       FARRIS 
LONDON     HATHAWAY 32.00
GLASGOW       JONES 28.00
MANCHESTER    SMITH 32.00
LONDON       FARRIS 62.00
```

```
SELECT FN.ID,
       FN.FIRST_NAME,
       SN.SECOND_NAME,
       AC.CITY,
       AC.AGE
FROM FIRST.NAME.TABLE AS FN
INNER JOIN SECOND.NAME.TABLE SN
      ON FN.ID=SN.ID
INNER JOIN CITY.AGE.TABLE AS CA
      ON SN.SECOND NAME=AC.SECOND_NAME
WHERE FN.ENTRY_DATE='09-SEP-19'
AND SN.ENTRY_DATE='09-SEP-19'
AND (CASE WHEN AC.CITY='LONDON' AND AC.AGE IS NOT NULL
               THEN AC.CITY='LONDON'
          ELSE AS.CITY='MANCHESTER' END)
```

Comment: Different tables for first and last name?!?

Comment: You should have one `cities` table, and one `persons` table (first name, last name, dob, and a city id foreign key to cities table.)

Comment: `City` table with `Second Name` and `Age` and `Second Name` is the FK relationship? So how do you accommodate for duplicate last names in the same City?

Comment: This is a simplified example of what I need to do but yes tables are different and I cannot create or edit tables just select from them.

Comment: This is where the problem is basically i need to join the second names where the city is London unless age is empty in which case the where clause should select manchester. Once you filter for city it is one for one relationship but I don't know how to create a filter which changes in the where clause.

Comment: The `Case` statement in the `Where` clause is only the left side of a criteria. You need the right side of the criteria. Basically you have, when your `Case` statement is met, `AND LONDON`. It's missing the operator and right side of the criteria.

Comment: Try this for the `Case`. `AND CA.City = Case When CA.Age IS NULL THEN 'Manchester' ELSE 'London' END` You alias your `City.Age` table as `CA`, but you reference it as `AC`.

Comment: Please also update your question to use either `"ENTRY DATE"` or `ENTRY_DATE`, but not `ENTRY DATE`(table definition and statement). Same for `CA.City=LONDON`, which should be `CA.City='London'` I guess.

Comment: As a complete aside, your DBMS is Oracle <version> (you can find the version of Oracle your database is running on from `SELECT VERSION FROM v$instance;`). Toad is a GUI (graphical user interface) that allows you to connect to the database and run queries, etc. It is not, in and of itself, a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can express this as boolean logic:

```
WHERE FN.ENTRY_DATE = DATE '2019-09-09' AND
      SN.ENTRY_DATE = DATE '2019-09-09' AND
      (AC.AGE IS NOT NULL AND AC.CITY = 'LONDON' OR
       AC.AGE IS NULL AND AC.CITY = 'MANCHESTER'
      )
```

This answers your question about how to implement the logic using SQL.  However, I'm not sure that is the logic that you really want.  I speculate that you really want a `LEFT JOIN` to the age table.

Comment: I attempted the above but it is not working as for Manchester the age is not null so it does not select the row it just returns the ones with London in them.